# How to get controller from area with ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

http://site.com/Admin/User/Index

Admin - area.

I need:

```
get controller Account (path /site.com/AccountController)
```

@Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account")

This gives me the following errors:

> "The IControllerFactory 'Web.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory'"
>   "did not return a controller for the name 'Account'."

Comment: Your 'I need' bit doesn't make sense - do you think you need to resolve a controller in a view? Also, can you put the real error in - it saves people guessing. BTW @Remo Gloor's answer is correct - the message suggests you have configured a controller factory called `Web.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory`. This needs to go away and you need to ensure that the one that Ninject.MVC3 puts in is the one that is actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Ninject.MVC3 extension instead of writing your own `NinjectControllerFactory`. It supports areas. https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3

Comment: it is installed, I do not know how to configure it

Comment: The link above tells you how to use this extension.